# key values of dictionary is not showing in html by django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I just start learning Django and I came across this problem in which my key values "hello world" of a key "hello" is not showing in the HTML page, I hope you guys help me to understand this code

homepage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>this is html page</h1>
{{ hello }}
</body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
import view

urlpatterns = [
    path('',view.homepage),
]
```

view.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def homepage(request):
    return render(request, "homepage.html", {'hello':'hello world'})
```

Comment: What if you tried wrapping `{{ hello }}` in a `<p>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p>{{ hello }}</p>
```

write your code inside the

tag